# JavaScript Trouble with div resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new to js and for the life of me can not figure out the issue with this function. I am just trying to resize the div's width on a page resize. The css is also included in case that has anything to do with it.

```
<div id="lowerPattern"></div>


<script>
    $( window ).bind("resize", function() {
        // Change the width of the div
        $("#lowerPattern").css('width', '300px');
    });
</script>


/*CSS*/
#lowerPattern {
    height: 99px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    /*Keeps div centered on resize*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kuaYV/

Have you made sure JQuery is loading properly? Also, try putting the function in `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).bind("resize", function(){
        // Change the width of the div
        $("#lowerPattern").css('width', '300px');
    });
});
```

Edit: If it's still not working, it could be something to do with the parent element's CSS. Also make sure you don't have any other elements with the same `id` attribute on the page.

Answer (score 0):

enclose your code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( window ).bind("resize", function(){
// Change the width of the div
$("#lowerPattern").css('width', '300px');
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a shot. I think it may have had something to do with my testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

DO you know that you must load Jquery?
You must either put the jquery source code into a file and save it or download it everytime you run the website with a CDN(Contact Delivery network.)

Also you must load Jquery. Go to their site and download the source. Save to a textfile with the .js extension.
After that write

```
<script type="text/Javascript" src="MyJquery.js"></script>
```

in the head area of the HTML

The other option is to use a CDN and write:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

This will load the jquery to your website

you must put the code into

$(document).ready(function(){

//put all your code here

});

If you are using a CDN check your net connection. If the internet connection is lost it will not load the Jquery while you are trying to run